# Group images by six Django templates

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make the forloop group the images into `<li>` of 6 plus a last li with remainder if the total number isn't a multiple of 6. Right now it doesn't do this correctly some of the tags aren't inside the li.

```
{% for movie in movies %}
  {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:6 %}
  <li>
  {% endif %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
    <li>
  {% endif %}
      <a href="{{ movie.get_absolute_url }}">
        {% thumbnail movie.picture "158x215" as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="">
        {% endthumbnail %}
        <p>{{ movie.name }}</p>
      </a>
  {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:6 %}
    </li>
  {% endif %}
  {% ifequal forloop.counter 5 %}
  <li>
  {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you want 6 images inside one `<li>` or 6 `<li>`'s each with an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to create a new `<li>` element after every 6 iterations.

```
<li>
{% for movie in movies %}

      <a href="{{ movie.get_absolute_url }}">
        {% thumbnail movie.picture "158x215" as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="">
        {% endthumbnail %}
        <p>{{ movie.name }}</p>
      </a>

  {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:6 %}
     </li>
     <li>
  {% endif %}

{%endfor%}

</li>
```